# PostGIS dependency conflicts (ubuntu 14)

Tags: apt, dependencies, postgresql, gis

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459737/installing-geodjango-postgis-package-broken) over on SO, but now I'm thinking the problem is mainly package management and belongs here.

Subsequent to all the detail that can be found in the original post, I have tried (sudo eliminated as redundant):

```
$ apt list | grep gdal | grep installed
gdal-bin/trusty,now 1.11.0+dfsg-1~exp2~trusty1 amd64 [installed]
libgdal1h/trusty,now 1.11.0+dfsg-1~exp2~trusty1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
$ apt-get purge gdal-bin
$ apt-get purge libdal1h
$ add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
$ apt-get update
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

so clearly something is misconfigured... I don't know what to check for on my side...

then

```
$ fab vagrant.Provision # see the original question above for what this is doing at the linux level
```

This still runs into the exact same `libdal1` v. `libgdal1h` dependency issue:

```
[localhost] sudo: DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --quiet --assume-yes postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
[localhost] out: {...}
[localhost] out: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
[localhost] out: requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
[localhost] out: distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
[localhost] out: or been moved out of Incoming.
[localhost] out: The following information may help to resolve the situation:
[localhost] out: 
[localhost] out: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
[localhost] out:  postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 : Depends: libgdal1 (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
[localhost] out:                               Recommends: postgis but it is not going to be installed
[localhost] out: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

more info :

```
vagrant@ubuntu-14:~$ apt-cache policy postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.1.3+dfsg-3.pgdg12.4+2
  Version table:
     2.1.3+dfsg-3.pgdg12.4+2 0
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
     2.1.2+dfsg-2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Have you tried using the stable versions instead of the unstable versions?

Comment: I have. See the edited question. Short answer: did, doesn't help.

Comment: Can you run `apt-cache policy postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1`? The version in the main repos depends on `libgdal1h`, which makes me think another PPA is providing the package.

Comment: good tip: edited the question

Comment: Well, there's your problem. Note the repo for the `2.1.3+dfsg-3.pgdg12.4+2` version; it's from PostgreSQL, but it's for Precise. That tends to mess stuff up. Go into `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and remove the line referencing that repo. Update and try to install again.

Comment: I can't just remove that line without knowing how to replace it. Or rather I can, but it's added again in the build process, so I need to have a replacement. I'm not a linux package guru, so perhaps I just don't quite understand the relationships, of course

Comment: I just looked at the SO question, and the page you linked to is for installing PostGIS, *which is already included in the main repo*. You should go back up to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/install/) page. I think Django (which should include GeoDjango) can be installed from the `python-django` package or using `pip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as @saircot895 lead me to discover, was a conflict between the repos. The specifics were not visible in the questions I asked, because I had not delved deeply enough into the Fabric script which was setting up the virtual Ubuntu box in question. In the event, the script was using the older "Precise" release for postgres itself, but postgis was looking on the newer "Trusty". Changing the postgres install (and the rest of the provisioning) to the newer release resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've sucessfully (without any broken dependencies) installed `postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.0` instead of `postgresql-9.1-postgis`. And database is working ok.